# PHP: Forget Password Module working unexpectedly

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap-4

I am making a simple forget password module.
User will enter his username, security question answer, and new password.
So if the user is found in the database table, the password will get updated
or else it will show an error.

FORM CODE :

```html
<form id="fogform" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="un" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Username:
                                        </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="un" placeholder="Enter your username" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-6" for="ques">Security
                                                Question:</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <select name="ques" class="form-control" required>
          <option value="" selected>Choose any:</option>
          <option value="In which city you were
                                                    born?">In which city you were born?
          </option>
          <option value="What was your first
                                                    pet's name?">What was your first pet's name?</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="answ" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Your Answer:
                                        </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answ" placeholder="Enter your answer" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="npwd" class="col-form-label col-md-6">New Password:
                                        </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="npass" placeholder="Enter a New Password" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="rpwd" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Retype Password:
                                        </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Retype the password" required>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-5 offset-2">
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
      <button type="submit" name="fogo" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infomod" form="fogform">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

PHP CODE:

```html
<?php

session_start();

$cn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "imedtalks");

if(isset($_POST['fogo']))
{
    $fogsql = "SELECT uname, passwd, que, ans FROM register WHERE passwd='".$_POST['pass']."' 
    AND que='".$_POST['ques']."' AND ans='".$_POST['ques']."' AND uname='".$_POST['un']."' ";
    
    $rslt=mysqli_query($cn, $fogsql);
    

if($_POST['npass'] === $_POST['pass'])
{

    if($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rslt))
    {
        $fogsql2 = "UPDATE register SET passwd='".$_POST['pass']."' WHERE que='".$_POST['ques']."' AND ans='".$_POST['ques']."'
        AND uname='".$_POST['un']."' ";
        
        if($cn->query($fogsql2) === TRUE)
        {
        echo " <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Password Reset Successful!')</script> ";
    
        echo " <script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('http://localhost/PROII/HomePage.php')</script> ";
        }
    }
    
    else
    {
    
        echo " <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Password Reset Unsuccessful! Try Again.')</script> ";
    
        echo " <script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('http://localhost/PROII/HomePage.php')</script> ";
    
    }


}   
else
{
    echo " <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Password Verification Failed! Try Again')</script> ";

    echo " <script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('http://localhost/PROII/HomePage.php')</script> ";
}

}


?>
```

So here, whenever i try the wrong way it gives unsuccessful message but even for right field data, it gives an error.
I am new to php, that's why i can't understand where its going wrong.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: Is this code for a purely academic purpose or is it something you're intending to deploy? As it stands, this code is **extremely hazardous** and has serious deficiencies that need to be patched immediately if this code is live.

Comment: You should not have $_POST['pass'] in your query. If you have forgot your password the query will.never be true unless you remembered it

Comment: @AdamHull still same, unsuccessful error is generated.

Comment: @tadman i am just learning it, not intended to deploy.

Comment: What everyone else said. But also, your SELECT query, you're searching for `ques` in the database column `ans`, so you're never going to find the answer they've entered.

Comment: Learning is great, don't get me wrong, but I'm not sure this is the best way to learn.  A login system is easy to get wrong and very hard to get right. Time's better spent studying existing implementations and learning how to use them effectively than in badly re-inventing the wheel. Most implementations are difficult enough to use, there will be lots of challenges, but they'll start out safe by default. This code is so full of holes it's difficult to itemize them all. [Writing secure applications is hard](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Cheat_Sheet_Series) even with the proper tools.